# Removing the "Chrome OS is missing or damaged" screen

Tags: chromebook

I installed Ubuntu and removed ChromeOS on my Chromebook using a live-boot USB drive and now when I boot up I have to press `CTRL+L` to boot. If I don't I see a screen that says `ChromeOS is missing or damaged`.

Is there a way that I can have the Chromebook boot right into Ubuntu without seeing that message? (FYI: I did not use Crouton or Chrubuntu to install -instead I used a ubuntu live boot external hard drive.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking a look a the GBB flags.

Follow this article 
[This should work](https://www.howtogeek.com/279308/how-to-restore-your-chromebooks-original-bios-and-software/) 
until you reach the part where it says ("Use the “Restore Stock Firmware (full)” option. Type “9” and press “Enter” to run it.")
 You will see option 4 is for setting boot options.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1005366)

Comment: Thank you for clarity, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: I clicked on the link and it says the link is not found.

Comment: @Crabtree You have anything else?

Comment: The hyperlink was edited and will take you to the correct page now.